# Horizontal data assigning in the table

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables:

```
project.sql
projectNo| title |
---------+-------+
17020002 | test  |
17020003 | test2 |

process.sql
projectNo| process | studio  |
---------+---------+---------+
17020002 | ANM     | STELLAR |
17020002 | BLD     |         |
17020003 | ANM KEY | APEX    |
17020003 | BLD     | PALETTE |
```

What I want to do is to create mysql query which will show studio names horizontally as headers of table and put 'x' where it matches:

So i want table to look like this:

```
| title         | APEX | BASECAMP | CANVAS | HORIZON | LAUNCHPAD | NEBULA | ORBIT | PALETTE | SANDBOX | STELLAR | THE CLIMB | TOONIGAMI | TREEHOUSE |
+---------------+------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Project test  |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         |         |           |           |           |
| ANM           |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         | x       |           |           |           |
| BLD           |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         |         |           |           |           |
| Project test2 |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         |         |           |           |           |
| ANM KEY       | x    |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         |         |           |           |           | 
| BLD           |      |          |        |         |           |        |       | x       |         |         |           |           |           |
```

The query i tried to use:

```
SELECT proc.projectNo, proc.title, 
    max(case when studio = "APEX" then "x" else "" end) as APEX,
    max(case when studio = "BASECAMP" then "x" else "" end) as BASECAMP,
    max(case when studio = "CANVAS" then "x" else "" end) as CANVAS,
    max(case when studio = "HORIZON" then "x" else "" end) as HORIZON,
    max(case when studio = "LAUNCHPAD" then "x" else "" end) as LAUNCHPAD,
    max(case when studio = "NEBULA" then "x" else "" end) as NEBULA,
    max(case when studio = "ORBIT" then "x" else "" end) as ORBIT,
    max(case when studio = "PALETTE" then "x" else "" end) as PALETTE,
    max(case when studio = "SANDBOX" then "x" else "" end) as SANDBOX,
    max(case when studio = "STELLAR" then "x" else "" end) as STELLAR,
    max(case when studio = "THE CLIMB" then "x" else "" end) as THECLIMB,
    max(case when studio = "TOONIGAMI" then "x" else "" end) as TOONIGAMI,
    max(case when studio = "TREEHOUSE" then "x" else "" end) as TREEHOUSE
    FROM process p1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT projectNo, title
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT projectNo, CONCAT('Project ', title) as title, 0 AS a FROM project
            UNION ALL
            SELECT projectNo, process, 1 AS a FROM process
        ) t
        ORDER BY projectNo, a, title
    )proc
    ON p1.projectNo = proc.projectNo
    GROUP BY proc.projectNO, proc.title
```

And by using this query i got:

```
| title         | APEX | BASECAMP | CANVAS | HORIZON | LAUNCHPAD | NEBULA | ORBIT | PALETTE | SANDBOX | STELLAR | THE CLIMB | TOONIGAMI | TREEHOUSE |
+---------------+------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ANM           |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         | x       |           |           |           |
| BLD           |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         | x       |           |           |           |
| Project test  |      |          |        |         |           |        |       |         |         | x       |           |           |           |
| ANM KEY       | x    |          |        |         |           |        |       | x       |         |         |           |           |           |
| BLD           | x    |          |        |         |           |        |       | x       |         |         |           |           |           | 
| Project test2 | x    |          |        |         |           |        |       | x       |         |         |           |           |           |
```

How can I achieve the result i want? thanks for help

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in some kind of application code, e.g. a bit of PHP

Comment: @Strawberry i run this query on phpmyadmin sql command line, not using it in a php code yet

Comment: Cool. So fix that. All you need is a nicely ordered array. Everything else can (and in my view, should) be done in PHP... oh, also you would probably want a table of studios

Answer (score 0):

You should use a left join
If you need a two leve hierarchy then you could use

```
select * from from (
  SELECT 
          0 as level,
          pj.projectNo as projectNo, 
          CONCAT('Project ', pj.title) as title, 
          null as APEX,
          null as BASECAMP,
          null as CANVAS,
          null as HORIZON,
          null as LAUNCHPAD,
          null as NEBULA,
          null as ORBIT,
          null as PALETTE,
          null as SANDBOX,
          null as STELLAR,
          null as THECLIMB,
          null as TOONIGAMI,
          null as TREEHOUSE
    FROM project as pj

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
          max(1), 
          pj.projectNo, 
          pc.process,
          max(case when pc.studio = "APEX" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "BASECAMP" then "x" else "" end), 
          max(case when pc.studio = "CANVAS" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "HORIZON" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "LAUNCHPAD" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "NEBULA" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "ORBIT" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "PALETTE" then "x" else "" end),
          max(case when pc.studio = "SANDBOX" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "STELLAR" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "THE CLIMB" then "x" else "" end),
          max(case when pc.studio = "TOONIGAMI" then "x" else "" end) ,
          max(case when pc.studio = "TREEHOUSE" then "x" else "" end) 
    FROM project as pj
    left join process  as  pc on pj.projectNo = pc.projectNo
    GROUP BY pj.projectNO, pj.title ) t
    order by t.level, t.projectNo, t.title
```

Comment: in that case i get only project name, but i need project name(title) and process also

Comment: I think the problem is in syntax. it gives me syntax problems. like 2 `from` in the beginning of the statement, or missed comma after `pc.process`, but even after fixing this errors still get more

Comment: I have update the answer .. removed  unuseful left join i first select and missing comma in second ..

Comment: Now gives error `Unknown column 'level' in 'group statement'`

Comment: Answer updated  adding a (fake) aggregation function to second select for avoid a group by without alias ..

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it:

```
/** start for getting titles**/
$sql = '
        SELECT proj_title, CONCAT(projectNo, " ", proj_title) AS title
        FROM (
            SELECT projectNo, CONCAT("Project ", title) AS proj_title, 0 AS a FROM project p1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DISTINCT projectNo, process, 1 AS a FROM process p2) t
        ORDER BY projectNo, a, title
        ';
$projects = [];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// for each title
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $projects[] = $data;
    $titles = array();
    $sql2 = '         
            SELECT a.* FROM
            (
                (
                  SELECT upr.projectNo, upr.process, p.stdid, p.studio_name, COALESCE(upr.num_appearences, 0) AS count
                  FROM studios p
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT CONCAT(upr.projectNo, " ", upr.process) AS process, projectNo, studio, COUNT(DISTINCT studio) AS num_appearences
                        FROM process upr
                        GROUP BY projectNo, process, studio   
                    )upr ON p.studio_name = upr.studio
                    AND upr.process = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['title']) . '"
                )
            ) AS a
            ORDER BY a.projectNo, a.studio_name, a.process';
    $rows = []; 
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $rows[] = $data2;
        $projectNo = $data['title'];
        $studioName = $data2['studio_name'];
        $titles[] = $studioName;
        $count = $data2['count'];

        if (!isset($allProcess[$projectNo])) 
            $allProcess[$projectNo] = [];

        if ($count) 
            $allProcess[$projectNo][$studioName] = $count;      
    }
    $titles = array_unique($titles); 
}
```

And the table:

```
<table class="paginated" style=" margin-right:10%;">
<?php
/** now do the printing of data **/
if ($allProcess)
{
    $header =
        '<th>Title</th>' .
        array_reduce(array_values($titles), function ($p, $n) {
            return $p . '<th>Studio ' . htmlspecialchars($n) . '</th>';
        });

    $body = '';
    /** loop through projects first instead **/
    foreach ($projects as $p) {
        $body .= '<tr>';
        $body .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($p['proj_title']) . '</td>';

        /** loop through titles or all process **/
        foreach ($titles as $t) {
            $row = $allProcess[$p['title']]; // e.g. Array ( [process] => Array ( [170001]...
            $r = isset($row) && isset($row[$t]) ? $row[$t] : ' ';
            $body .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($r) . '</td>';
        }
        $body .= '</tr>';
    }
    echo "<thead>$header</thead><tbody>$body</tbody>";
}
?>    
</table>
```